# How to create JAXBContext in EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

`JAXBContext.newInstance()` method receives `Map` with properties as a parameter.

Which properties and how should I specify to make `JAXBContext` instance informed about several files with xml-mappings?

[Example](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html) shows how to specify only one file in a way which is not acceptable in real systems (i.e. with `new File(address)`). Instead of this I need to use `classLoader.getResource()` which returns `URL` object.

Thanks!

UPD:

When I try to instantiate JAXBContext I get this exeption:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink-oxm-xml" is not supported
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:118)
    ...
```

It's obvious that `jaxb.properties` file is not found at start up. Where should I put it? (I'm using maven, and actually I've tried to put it to `/target/jaxb.properties`, `/target/classes/jaxb.properties`, `/target/classes/META-INF/definitions/jaxb.properties` - it's near xml-mapping file, and `/target/classes/com/myproject/experiment/jaxb.properties` - it's near the class which tries to instantiate JAXBContext).

Answer (score 2):

The E[clipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) external bindings file can be in any of (or a List of) the following formats:

- java.io.File
- java.io.InputStream
- java.io.Reader
- java.net.URL
- javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader
- javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader
- javax.xml.transform.Source
- org.w3c.dom.Node
- org.xml.sax.InputSource

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you also need to include a file named jaxb.properties with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: thanks! Is it possible to set up multiple xml-mapping files? (Or maybe there's any mechanism which allows to import all mappings in one xml-file - like in Spring configuration?)

Comment: @Roman - You can also pass a List of bindings files in any of the above formats.

Comment: @Roman - The jaxb.properties file needs to be in the same package as the model classes.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: will it work if jaxb.properties is placed in the same package but in another module?